# Can I bind Dropdownlist (DDL) inside Gridview (GV) to the datasource of DDL rather than GV?

Tags: gridview, drop-down-menu

If yes how. Scenarios is : I have GV which as SQLDatasource1. I have DDL inside GV in edit template. DDL is using SQLDatasource2. By default when I want to bind values to DDL, it give options of the GV Datsource not the DDL's datasource. Neither works by the way.

What I am doing is fetching values from a 2nd table inside the DDL. I want those values to be updated in side table1 which I am updating. So table1 has references in table2. I want to update these references using DDL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx) is here. You do not need any C# code for this.